# Materializecss modal not open when page loading

Tags: jquery, materialize

I have latest materialize css and Jquery. I try to a warning message by using modal when page loading completely.
But never working

```
<div id="myModal"  class="modal bottom-sheet">
<div class="modal-content">
  <font size="2">Sitemizden en iyi şekilde faydalanabilmeniz için çerezler kullanılmaktadır. Bu siteye giriş yaparak çerez kullanımını kabul etmiş sayılıyorsunuz</font>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" style="font-size: smaller;margin-top: 0px;height: 30px;">Agree</a>
</div>
```

And the script is like that,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.modal1').modal('open');
    });                             
</script>
```

If I use button to open modal, it works. So CSS and JQuery works
Have you any idea?

Comment: check the selector `'.modal1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working well for me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal().show();
  $('.modal-close').click(function() {
    $('.modal').hide();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="myModal"  class="modal">

<div class="modal-content">
  <font size="2">Sitemizden en iyi şekilde faydalanabilmeniz için çerezler kullanılmaktadır. Bu siteye giriş yaparak çerez kullanımını kabul etmiş sayılıyorsunuz</font>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" style="font-size: smaller;margin-top: 0px;height: 30px;">Agree</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got it now. I put my modal div into page. So modal is opening behind of page. Now change modal div place.It works.Thnx

Answer (score 1):

You looks like defined your modal with **id** selector so i think you should to use modal function like that:

```
$('#myModal').modal('open');
```

Comment: I did. Still not works.But inspection console shows an error. that: TypeError: this.M_Modal is undefined . this message shows  in materialize.js -> this.M_Modal[methodOrOptions]();

Comment: @TevfikCeydeliler As i see in the materialize documention you should to initialize it first like that `$('.modal').modal();` before use the modal functions, try it.